# ExpandableListView not showing all the headers and children

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Expandable view is not creating list of all the headers and the children, only one group header is showing with no children in it, just the down arrow.
On click it is just showing up arrow and nothing else.

```
public class CategoryWise extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String,List<String>> listDataChild;
DataBaseClass db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_wise);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ExpandableCategory);
    prepareListData();
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);


}

public void prepareListData()
{
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
  }
}
```

this `ExpandableListAdapter` class is as follows

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> _listChildData;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String,List<String>> listChildData)
{
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listChildData  = listChildData;

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listChildData.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this._listChildData.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

When I was unable to find the solution i tried this code from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)
Please help.

[image: Here is the screenshot for the reference]

```
list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show me your child item view (xml)

Comment: Yeah sure...i edited the question @HoàngVũNam

Comment: try to change android:layout_height="match_parent"> to wrap_content

Comment: @HoàngVũNam its still the same